# C# Regex: Check if the given directory in a net use command contains whitespaces

Tags: c#, regex, whitespace, quotation-marks, net-use

I am programming a tool to standardize batch-files and I use a regular expression to validate every [`net use`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx) command in it.

I'm stuck at the directory that is given to the command. The standard syntax of the command in this case is: `net use [devicename]: [path] [/user:"\domain\user"] [password] [/persistent:no]` where the `[path]` can contain **whitespaces**. If **`true`** it has to be between **quotationmarks**(`"`), otherwise there have to be no **quotationmarks**. The user and password are optional. The path can contain the following special characters (`!`,`,`,`+`,`.`,`-`).

The following regular expression **allows** a path **in quotationmarks without whitespaces** and **disallows** a path with **sequenced whitespaces with quotationmarks** or **without whitespaces and quotationmarks**. The regex may contain syntaxerrors, I tested it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) with PCRE:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^net use [a-z]:\s
(?(?=[\S]+\s[\S]+)(""\\\\[\w.\-,!+]+(\s[\w.\-,!+]+)*(\\[\w.\-,!+]+(\s[\w.\-,!+]+)*)*"")|
(\\\\[\w.\-,!+]+(\\[\w.\-,!+]+)*))
(\s\/user:""[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*"")?\s\/persistent:no$");
```

The necessary part of the regex is:

```
(?(?=[\S]+\s[\S]+)(""\\\\[\w.\-,!+]+(\s[\w.\-,!+]+)*(\\[\w.\-,!+]+(\s[\w.\-,!+]+)*)*"")|
(\\\\[\w.\-,!+]+(\\[\w.\-,!+]+)*))
```

How do I afford the expression to do it vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you with the directory matching.

Let's start with the way that directories can be prefixed.

`./` e.g. `./some/path/to/some/file.txt`

`../` e.g. `../some/path/to/some/file.txt`

`/` e.g. `/some/path/to/some/file.txt`

`<blank>` e.g. `some/path/to/some/file.txt`

We can describe this with this regex.

`(\.\/|\.\.\/|\/)?` Definitely unsightly, but it works.

Here's an expanded diagram of our regex before it gets condensed into a one-liner.

```
"                   # opening quotation mark
(\.\/|\.\.\/|\/)?   # optional / ./ ../
[^\/"]++            # match content after opening / ./ ../
(\/[^\/"]++)+       # match /<CONTENT> repetitively
"                   # closing quotation mark
```

Let's wrap the expression in spaces (maybe more than one) to be safe. `[ ]+`

```
[ ]+"(\.\/|\.\.\/|\/)?[^\/"]++(\/[^\/"]++)+"[ ]+
```

This should match paths with spaces as long as they're wrapped in quotes. [Here are some trials that I ran with it](https://regex101.com/r/fM2rF5/1).

As for paths without spaces that aren't enclosed in quotations try this regex.

```
[ ]+(\.\/|\.\.\/|\/)?[^\/\s]++(\/[^\/\s]++)+[ ]+
```

It shares features with the other regex, so hopefully you can use that as a reference point to understanding this one. I'm not sure how much this helps your problem overall, but I guess it should shed a little light onto paths portions.

Oh, and to use them in conjunction, just your the regex `or` operator, `|`. Should look something like this:

```
(                                                # begin capturing group
[ ]+"(\.\/|\.\.\/|\/)?[^\/"]++(\/[^\/"]++)+"[ ]+ # paths with spaces
|                                                # or
[ ]+(\.\/|\.\.\/|\/)?[^\/\s]++(\/[^\/\s]++)+[ ]+ # paths w/o spaces
)                                                # end capturing group
```

Good luck!

Comment: The expression with spaces accepts paths wrapped in quotationmarks without spaces ([link](https://regex101.com/r/fM2rF5/1)). Is there a way to disallow this? For example with a conditional expression that the path must have one space at least.

Comment: @RNGsusCryst is it problematic that paths w/o spaces would have quotation marks? Isn't that valid formatting nonetheless?

Comment: @RNGsusCryst `(?<=\s)(?<!")(?:\.\/|\.\.\/|\/)[^\s]+(?!")(?=\s)` this will match only paths that you described in your comment. Try it out in the link you provided previously. Not sure how you would combine all of these though.

Comment: @wcaroll No, it is not problematic, the code is valid nonetheless. I was interested, if there is a solution for this problem. I will wrap all `[paths]` in **quotationmarks** as you suggested. That will provide a better perfomance for the program than my regex. Many thanks for your help.